# Recover windows 10 installation, grub does not detect it, unsafe state upon mounting

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub

I'm pretty sure I did something 1-2 months ago that borked my windows installation (I forgot what it was), now I can't boot into it, the partition is still there and I can see my files. **But** I can only mount it readonly and not read&write, when I try to mount normally.

```
$ sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/nvme0n1p2 /mnt/disk/       
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Could not mount read-write, trying read-only
```

The device does exist on gparted.

[image]

Checking the reserved partition yield this.

```
Unable to detect file system! Possible reasons are:
- The file system is damaged
- The file system is unknown to GParted
- There is no file system available (unformatted)
- The device entry /dev/nvme0n1p1 is missing
```

[image]

I found that one needs to disable fast startup to make windows works, but with the way things are, I cannot even boot to windows 10 to disable fast startup or to fully shutdown.

I have tried:

- os-prober (not working not detected)
- `sudo update-grub` (not working also)
- `sudo update-grub2` (not working also)

Is there anyway to recover my windows 10 installation ?

Comment: You should be able to directly boot Windows from the one time boot menu of  your UEFI/BIOS. The same menu you boot live installer or any other repair/recovery flash drive. If Windows does not boot from UEFI boot menu, then you have major Windows issues. F8 may get a recovery mode. Or you may need to boot your Windows repair/recovery flash drive.